# Referência indefinida no C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou estudando c++ e encontrei um problema na hora de trabalhar com orientação a objetos, segui alguns tutoriais mas não funcionou.

**Conta.h**

```
#ifndef CONTA_H
#define CONTA_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Conta{

    private:
        string nome;
        int idade;

    public:
        string getNome();
        int getIdade();
};

#endif // CONTA_H
```

**Conta.cpp**

```
#include "Conta.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string Conta::getNome(){
    return nome;
}

int Conta::getIdade(){
    return idade;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Conta.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Conta p;

    cout << p.getNome() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Quando eu compilo o código ele me traz esse erro.

```
undefined reference to `Conta::getNome()'
```

Obs: minha ide é o CodeBlocks.

Comment: Provavelmente não está compilando o `Conta.cpp` junto.

Comment: eu fiz um include no meu main.cpp ( #include "Conta.cpp" ) ele funcionou, mas fazer isso é uma boa prática ou está errado?

Comment: Não faça isto. Funcionar não significa que está certo.

Comment: Obrigado bigown, o problema era na hora da compilação mesmo, instalei o dev c++ e rodou de primeira.

Comment: Agora você tem um problema a mais :D

Comment: mas não vou usar ele não :) estou testando outros compiladores

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma boa forma de solucionar esse problema porque toda vez que fizer uma alteração no arquivo Conta.cpp, vai precisar recompilar o main.cpp.

O melhor seria acertar a forma como está compilando para que gere todos os objetos necessários.